# windows how to enable utf-8 file system support

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Its possible to enable utf-8 file system in windows 2003 server?. I want to create a chinese/japanese file name on my windows server.

Any help that must be appreciated......

thanks

Comment: The NTFS file system has been Unicode-enabled for the past 19 years.  Whatever switch needs to be flipped in your programming tool to use it is unclear from your question.

Comment: The file system uses uses UTF-16. To create a Chinese/Japanese file name, convert your UTF-8 string to UTF-16, then create it with the UTF-16 name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UTF-16 file name encoding.